# How can I put a div occupying full body height

Tags: html, css

I have a menu, and Im trying to wrap it inside of yellow div, and I want that this div (yellow) to occupy the whole height of the green square, no matter how big is the green square content, for example, if the orange square increases, the yellow div should increase as well

[image]

here is a snippet:

```css
.top-menu{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0px;
    
    
}

.main-content{
  
    position: relative;
  
    width: 96.5%;
    left: 3.5%;
    
    
}

.wrapper{
    display: fixed;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.left-menu{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3.5%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<body style="border:5px solid blue">
  
  <div class="top-menu" style="border:1px solid red;height: 60px;">



</div>


<div class="wrapper"style="border:5px solid green">

    <div class="left-menu" style="border:3px solid yellow">
      
       <p>Here is where I want to put my menu and I want that this div to be as tall as the pink div</p>

    </div>

    <div class="main-content" style="border:5px solid orange;">
     <p>O que é o Lorem Ipsum?
O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum.

Porque é que o usamos?
É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).


De onde é que ele vem?
Ao contrário da crença popular, o Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente texto aleatório. Tem raízes numa peça de literatura clássica em Latim, de 45 AC, tornando-o com mais de 2000 anos. Richard McClintock, um professor de Latim no Colégio Hampden-Sydney, na Virgínia, procurou uma das palavras em Latim mais obscuras (consectetur) numa passagem Lorem Ipsum, e atravessando as cidades do mundo na literatura clássica, descobriu a sua origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), por Cícero, escrito a 45AC. Este livro é um tratado na teoria da ética, muito popular durante a Renascença. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." aparece de uma linha na secção 1.10.32.

O pedaço mais habitual do Lorem Ipsum usado desde os anos 1500 é reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. As secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" do Cícero também estão reproduzidos na sua forma original, acompanhados pela sua tradução em Inglês, versões da tradução de 1914 por H. Rackham.

Onde posso arranjar algum?O que é o Lorem Ipsum?
O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum.

Porque é que o usamos?
É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).
</p>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Expected output
[image]

The height of yellow square is the same that green square

Can someone please help me?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
Hi,
you have to change the position of the .left-menu to absolute.
So his position is absolute to his relative parent here .wrapper

```css
.top-menu{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0px;  
}

.main-content{
  
    position: relative;
  
    width: 96.5%;
    left: 3.5%;  
}
   .wrapper {
       display: fixed;
       position: relative;
       width: 100%;
   }

   .left-menu {
       position: absolute;
       height: 100%;
       width: 3.5%;
       float: left;
       z-index: 0;
       overflow: visible;
   }
```

```html
<body style="border:5px solid blue">
  
  <div class="top-menu" style="border:1px solid red;height: 60px;">



</div>


<div class="wrapper"style="border:5px solid green">

    <div class="left-menu" style="border:3px solid yellow">
      
       <p>Here is where I want to put my menu and I want that this div to be as tall as the pink div</p>

    </div>

    <div class="main-content" style="border:5px solid orange;">
     <p>O que é o Lorem Ipsum?
O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum.

Porque é que o usamos?
É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).


De onde é que ele vem?
Ao contrário da crença popular, o Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente texto aleatório. Tem raízes numa peça de literatura clássica em Latim, de 45 AC, tornando-o com mais de 2000 anos. Richard McClintock, um professor de Latim no Colégio Hampden-Sydney, na Virgínia, procurou uma das palavras em Latim mais obscuras (consectetur) numa passagem Lorem Ipsum, e atravessando as cidades do mundo na literatura clássica, descobriu a sua origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), por Cícero, escrito a 45AC. Este livro é um tratado na teoria da ética, muito popular durante a Renascença. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." aparece de uma linha na secção 1.10.32.

O pedaço mais habitual do Lorem Ipsum usado desde os anos 1500 é reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. As secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" do Cícero também estão reproduzidos na sua forma original, acompanhados pela sua tradução em Inglês, versões da tradução de 1914 por H. Rackham.

Onde posso arranjar algum?O que é o Lorem Ipsum?
O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum.

Porque é que o usamos?
É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).
</p>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi @Zach, you could try to add an explanation so the asker understand better what specific codes is changed :)

Comment: Hi @HastaDhana, I edit my post. Thanks it's my first post. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
.top-menu{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0px;
    
    
}

.main-content{
  
    position: relative;
  
    width: 96.5%;
    left: 3.5%;
    
    
}

.wrapper{
    display: fixed;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.left-menu{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3.5%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<body style="border:5px solid blue">
  



</div>


<div class="wrapper"style="border:5px solid green">

    <div class="left-menu" style="border:3px solid yellow">
      
       <p>Here is where I want to put my menu and I want that this div to be as tall as the pink div</p>

    </div>

    <div class="main-content" style="border:5px solid orange;">
     <p>O que é o Lorem Ipsum?
O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum.

Porque é que o usamos?
É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).


De onde é que ele vem?
Ao contrário da crença popular, o Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente texto aleatório. Tem raízes numa peça de literatura clássica em Latim, de 45 AC, tornando-o com mais de 2000 anos. Richard McClintock, um professor de Latim no Colégio Hampden-Sydney, na Virgínia, procurou uma das palavras em Latim mais obscuras (consectetur) numa passagem Lorem Ipsum, e atravessando as cidades do mundo na literatura clássica, descobriu a sua origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), por Cícero, escrito a 45AC. Este livro é um tratado na teoria da ética, muito popular durante a Renascença. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." aparece de uma linha na secção 1.10.32.

O pedaço mais habitual do Lorem Ipsum usado desde os anos 1500 é reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. As secções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" do Cícero também estão reproduzidos na sua forma original, acompanhados pela sua tradução em Inglês, versões da tradução de 1914 por H. Rackham.

Onde posso arranjar algum?O que é o Lorem Ipsum?
O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum.

Porque é que o usamos?
É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).
</p>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: No, I changed my question to try to explain myself better.
The idea is maintaining the same divs, but the yellow Height always at the same height of green div

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like: 
heigth: 100%